# Object not defined or null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wrote a JavaScript file named global.js that has the following contents:

```
;

var Globals = 
{
    function getAppRoot() {
        if (typeof (jQuery) !== "undefined")
            return $("#ApplicationRoot").attr("href");
    };

    appRoot : getAppRoot();
};
```

Then in my HTML file (ASP.NET MVC project), I included my JavaScript file like so:

```
<link rel = "home" id = "ApplicationRoot" 
    href = "@Url.Content("~/")" />

<script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src = "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/global.js")" 
    type = "text/javascript"></script>
```

And then, in the HTML file, inside a SCRIPT tag, I write:

```
$(document).ready( 
    function() { 
        alert("Globals.appRoot = " + window.Globals.appRoot); 
    } );
```

However, when I run the code, it tells me that `Globals` is undefined.

**UPDATE**
Thank you, all. I just noticed that I'd forgotten the equal to sign (assignment operator) for one.

Another important thing that I observe now (which I wasn't fully sure of) is: I am assuming from your comments that an object declaration like so:

```
var foo = { /* cannot have anything that does not adhere to the bar : gar syntax? */ }
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**
The thing is: if I made `appRoot` a method by doing so:

```
var Globals = 
{
    appRoot : function() { }
};
```

or like so:

```
var Globals = 
{
    appRoot : function getAppRoot() { }
}
```

The client would have to invoke `appRoot` with a set of following parenthesis. I would like for `appRoot` to be a property instead of a method. How do I do that?

**FINAL UPDATE**
I now have changed my code to read as follows:

```
// globals.js
// I understand that the starting semi-colon is not 
// required. I'd left it in for reasons that it is used
var Globals = 
{
    appRoot : $("#ApplicationRoot").attr("href");
};


// inside the HTML file in $(document).ready();

if (tyepof(Globals) == "undefined" || Globals == null)
  alert("Globals is either undefined or null");
else
  alert("Globals.appRoot = " + Globals.appRoot);
```

I get the alert message **Globals is either undefined or null**.

**ANSWER**
Okay, finally. Thanks for all your help. I had another minor syntax error in the object declaration/initialization of the `Globals` object.

Since `appRoot` was a member of the object, and I was using the object initializer syntax, I should not have terminated the declaration of `appRoot` with a semi-colon. Instead, I should either have used a comma or just left it without any terminating character since it was the last (and the only member of `Globals`).

Comment: doesn't really look like javascript.

Comment: There are several syntax errors in the code. If you look at the JavaScript console in your browser (if you don't have one, use a more modern browser :-) ), you'll see various messages pointing out the errors. *Edit: Even as of your edit just now.*

Comment: *"`var foo = { /* cannot have anything that does not adhere to the bar : gar syntax? */ }`"* Correct. It's called an *object initializer* (sometimes an "object literal"), details in [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5).

Comment: Thanks. I remember the name. I don't know why I didn't mention it in my post.

Comment: If you want to have `appRoot` a value/object, don't assign it to a function.

Comment: @thgaskell Oh, yes, how stupid of me. Sorry. I can't think straight when I have a language I haven't spent a lot of time in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `global.js` should look more like this:

```
//; << not needed
var Globals = /*equal to missing*/
{
    appRoot : function getAppRoot() {
        if (typeof (jQuery) !== "undefined")
            return $("#ApplicationRoot").attr("href");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-write your globals.js, something like this should work:

```
var Globals = {
    appRoot : function() {
        if (typeof (jQuery) !== "undefined") {
            return $("#ApplicationRoot").attr("href");
        }
    }
};
```